# Rails adding multiple objects to an empty array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create an array and add multiple objects to it, but I wouldn't know how to start. Help please.

-- edit

This is what I have so far.

```
@players = @user.players
@team = Team.all
@players.each do |player|
  @t = @team.find(player.team_id)
  @teams = Array.new
  @teams.push(@t)
end
```

Comment: How about `arr = Array.new, arr << obj1, arr << obj2, ...`? Have you read any Ruby documentation?

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html

Comment: well I've tried arr << obj1 but its not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot going on in your code snippet that is making it not work (or at the very least is unnecessary). You shouldn't be creating a new array in every iteration of your loop. Something along the lines of this should be much better:

```
@players = @user.players
@teams = Array.new
@players.each do |player|
  @teams << Team.find(player.team_id)
end
```

This will solve your original problem, but it's certainly not the best way of going about what you're trying to do. Add the following to your `Player` and `User` models:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :players
  has_many :teams, through: :players
end
```

Then, in order to get the teams you're looking for, you can simplify your code to the following:

```
@teams = @user.teams
```

You should try going through the documentation not only for [ruby arrays](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html), but also the Rails guide for [Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html). Also, in the future try posting the snippet of code first, in order to provide more context to your issue.